# Python Validation Error: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have these all installed

```
django-nonrel 
djangotoolbox
mongodb-engine
python 2.7.2.5
django 1.5.2
```

I successfully got my application to run with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And I configured the app to link to my index.html page where I can see my heading and everything. The application seems to be working without error but I can't get any mongodb integration.

---

Before I was getting this error:

```
   $ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 469, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/marcochiang/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS.insert(0, 'django_mongodb_engine')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Until I found out that I had to change

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...apps
)
```

to

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...apps
]
```

Which makes no sense. As soon as I fixed that I get

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 469, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/Users/marcochiang/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/base.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.ops = DatabaseOperations(self)
  File "/Users/marcochiang/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/base.py", line 28, in __init__
    super(NonrelDatabaseOperations, self).__init__()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I can't figure out where to find the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

SOURCES:
(settings.py)

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'testdb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '27017',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': False,
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the full traceback.

Comment: Which django you are using ? if 1.4 it should be `INSTALLED_APPS = (...)`

Comment: When I look at my site packes it says I have django 1.3.7 but when I type in

`python`
`import django`
`django.VERSION`

I get 1.5.2